# XSD:Controlling the restriction on length of xml element based on that element's attribute value using XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Following is the sample XML:

```
 <PatientName>
     <FamilyName updatable="2">Bob</FamilyName>
  </PatientName>
```

Currently using XSD is like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="reviewFamilyname">  
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">   
        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>  
    </xs:restriction>  
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="FamilyName" nillable="true">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="reviewFamilyname">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="updatable"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Currently i am using a restriction on family name that it's max length should be 20 characters.
i am using XSD 1.0 and i want to apply restriction to FamilyName element based on the attribute value of FamilyName element. I want to disable restriction when,

The attribute(updatable) value equals to 2 in FamilyName element.

And attribute(updatable) value equals to 1 and FamilyName element value is null.

In all other scenarios restriction should be enabled.How should i change the XSD to full fill these requirements,Is this possible?And if so How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSD 1.0 the type of an element's content can't depend on the value of its attributes.

In XSD 1.1 you can achieve this using the feature called **conditional type assignment**.

You would want something like this:

```
<xs:element name="FamilyName" type="xs:anyType">
  <xs:alternative test="@updateable = 1" type="...."/>
  <xs:alternative test="@updateable = 2" type="...."/>
  <xs:alternative type="...."/>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Could you please provide the exact code for the XSD. It will be really helpful.

Comment: how should i change my XSD schema version?

Comment: There are three known XSD 1.1 processors: Saxon, Xerces, and Altova. Install one of them.